# how to show only the repeated element?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

Im new to Haskell.

How to  show only the  repeated elements ?

Given as input: `bbbool`, expected output: `bo`

I found a way to do this from internet:

```
import qualified Data.Set as Set

dup :: Ord a => [a] -> Maybe a
dup xs = dup' xs Set.empty
  where dup' [] _ = Nothing
        dup' (x:xs) s = if Set.member x s 
                           then Just x
                           else dup' xs (Set.insert x s)

dupString :: (Ord a, Show a) => [a] -> [Char]
dupString x = case dup x of
                  Just x  -> "First duplicate: " ++ (show x)
                  Nothing -> "No duplicates"
```

But the problem is, it will only show the first repeated element.
for example : `bbbool = b`

I hope that my question is clear.

Comment: Do you want only the _adjacent_ duplicates, or any duplicates (which is what `dup` does)? I.e., should `dup "bboolol"` yield `"bol"` or just `"bo"`? If the former, in which order should the elements appear, or does it not matter? And do you have any performance (specifically, computational-complexity) constraints?

Comment: Any duplicates.  I want this:  "bbbool" = bo  , the order doesn't matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple way to do this would be, assuming you only look for adjacent repeated elements:

```
import Data.List (group)

findRepeating :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]
findRepeating = map head . filter ((> 1) . length) . group
```

You may want to sequence it with `nub` to deal with repeated elements, since for "bbbXaaaXbbb" it returns "bab".

Edit: if you meant all repeating elements, this should do:

```
import qualified Data.Map as M

findRepeating :: (Foldable k, Ord a) => t a -> [a]
findRepeating = M.keys . M.filter (> 1) . foldr (\x acc -> M.insertWith (+) x 1 acc) M.empty
```

This approach counts how many times each element shows up and then returns those that happened to appear more than once. The order in which they are returned is undefined.

Comment: I recommend using [`fromListWith`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.2.1/docs/Data-Map-Lazy.html#v:insertWith) instead of that manual fold. But it's a matter of taste.